# Angular2 , observable service , which is the best practice

Tags: angular, observable

I have a service which must call http to get data , process these data and returns converted data in an Observable

```
 _callHttp(): Observable<Array<element>> {
    return this._http.get(this._Url).map(res => this._extractData(res));
}

_extractData(res): element[] {
       return res.json().map(t => new element().fromJson(t));
 }


getOrganigramByName(name, language): Observable<element[]> {
    let list = new Array<element>();
    this._callHttp().subscribe(res=> list.push(res));
    let filteredList: Array<element> = this.filterList(list,name, language);
    return Observable.of(filteredList);
} 


filterList(list,name,language):Array<element>{
  let result : new Array<element>();
  list.forEach(res => {
     if (res.name==="albert"){
       result.push(res);
     }
   })
   return result
```

}

In method filterList , list is empty
I don't want to include filterList method in subcribe

what is the best way to do that ?

Comment: *some elment fields are used as element.name*: what does that mean? What is the code?

Comment: element is a class. export class element{name:string,lastname:string,...}, thus I want to access to element.name

Comment: In `getOrganigramByName` function, you define `list`, bind it in the `subscribe` callback but it looks like you never use it. What's the point of creating it for nothing ? ^^

Comment: I have edit my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem is that **Observable** are async.

```
let list = new Array<element>();

this._callHttp().subscribe(res=> {
    // This will happened sometimes in the futur, maybe in 5 seconds.
    list.push(res);
});

// But this will happened instantly, so list is still an empty array
let filteredList: Array<element> = this.filterList(list,name, language);

return Observable.of(filteredList);
```

So you cannot expect `list` to be anything else thant an empty array by the time you call `this.filterList`.

I think a better way of doing it is to use functionnal like methods like `.map` or `.filter`.

```
getOrganigramByName(name, language): Observable<element[]> {
    return this._callHttp().map(list => {
      return this.filterList(list, name, language);
    });
} 

filterList(list:element[], name, language):element[]{
  return list.filter(elem => {
    return elem.name === 'albert';
  });
}
```

I simulate your problem on a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HZropMpVvLoBeVElo4AW?p=preview).

My `_callHttp` is just a simulation of your http request and json parsing.

```
_callHttp(): Observable<element[]> {
  return Observable.of([{name:'bob'}, {name:'john'}, {name:'albert'}]);
}
```